# how to download photos from remote server to iphone app?

Tags: iphone, database

My situation is that I am making a uitableviewcontroller with uitableviewcells having a thumb nail or picture on the left, text on the right. All data is stored in a remote server. I have made a php to communicate with backend batabase and generate JSON to pass the data to iphone through http. However, I don't know how to do the same thing to photos. Please suggest me someway to do it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As Mundi said it already.

And make sure that you load them asynchronously.

There is a nice tutorial on this page:
http://www.markj.net/iphone-asynchronous-table-image/

Comment: Thank you for the reminder and the tutorial. That's really helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are using `NSURLConnection` to fetch your data from the server. Do this:

Collect the photo data into an `NSData` object.
In the `didFinishLoading` method use this to create the images:

```
UIImage *thumbnailImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:downloadedData];
// don't forget to discard the downloaded Data and release the image
```

The actual setup of your cells might be more complicated. The way I do it is to check in each call to `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` if I have cached the image, if not I pass to URL of the image to a `NSURLConnection`. I keep the open connections in an array and eliminated them when each download finishes or the view disappears. Let me know if you need more hints...